# Show if vector is in Span

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A = [image]  and

b= [image]

Columns of A are denoted as columns vectors **a1,a2,a3,a4**

W = Span(**a1,a2,a3,a4**)

Question : Show that **b** is in W

Here is an attempt at answering this question:

To show that **b** in W we have to show that **b** can be expressed in terms **a1,a2,a3,a4**. So we construct a linear system of 3 equations and 4 unknowns.

What I do not understand is that that system would produce 4 coordinates(x1,x2,x3,x4) where **b** requires only 3.

Comment: A is 3*4 matrix . Ax=b and b is 3*1 so we can conclude x is 4*1 . B is not x1=2 x2=3 and x3=6 , 2,3 and 6 are the result of 3x1-1x2+x3+2x4 and etc

Comment: You can use augmented matrix ans row echolon form of it to achieve your needed answer

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: With regards to using augmented matrix and row echelon I do end up with x = (1/3, -1/3, -10/3). Which means that to prove that b is in span, we have to show Ax=b. We have x = (1/3, -1/3, -10/3). So this could be a solution, but I would like to test it, however cannot multiply Ax as rows not equals to columns...

Answer (score 1):

We seek to show that there exists a non-zero solution $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^T$ (edit: added the transpose) to the equation $Ax = b$. As you pointed out, the system is "over-determined". A priori, there are several possibilities, and it might or might not be that $Ax = b$ admits a non-zero solution. Now, at least, the problem is reduced to one of solving a matrix equation, which in principle we know how to do.

---

4 = number of things being summed

3 = number of components in each summand

No matter how many vectors of dimension $3 \times 1$ we add together, the result is still $3 \times 1$. In this case, we're adding four vectors of dimension $3 \times 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Solve:

$a*
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
3\\
1\\
-1\\
\end{array}
\right)
$
$+b*\left(
\begin{array}{c}
-1\\
2\\
-3\\
\end{array}
\right)$
$+c*\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1\\
2\\
\end{array}
\right)$
$+d*\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2\\
1\\
-4\\
\end{array}
\right)$
$=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2\\
3\\
6\\
\end{array}
\right)$

If there is a solution to the system of linear equations, the vector lies in the span!

Comment: So this is interesting, by trying to solve the above system, you are not going to come up with the value of d. What does it mean ? Does it mean that it can be any value and therefore b in in the span?

Comment: No the vector which might be the solution or one of the solutions is gonna be a $4x1$-vector

Comment: When you multiply 3x4-matrix A with a 4x1 vector t, youll get a 3x1 vector b as a result! A*t=b

Answer (score 0):

Why should $\mathbf{b}$ require “four coordinates”? You have four vectors and you want to see whether $\mathbf{b}$ is a linear combination thereof; if this is the case, you'll need *four* coefficients, one for each among $\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\mathbf{a}_3,\mathbf{a}_4$.

These are not “coordinates”, just coefficients for the vectors. Surely, if $\mathbf{b}$ belongs to the span, there will be infinitely many solutions, because four vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are certainly linearly dependent.